# Can we ignore the generation side of the method described in density estimation using Real NVP?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, approximate-inference, normalizing-flow

First appologies if my question is stupid. I am studying the paper "Density estimation using real NVP" by Dinh, Sohl-Dickstein and Bengio. [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08803.pdf)

The paper presented a nice idea that the generation function is an exact inverse of the inference function. To apply the maximum likelihood optimization, the determinant of Jacobian matrix of the generation funciton must be available. However, if the generation function is already known from the inference function, can we just ignore the generation side? To get the inference function, we just maximize $p_Z(f(x))$ given a prio, which is the first term in Eq. 3.

If we do this, we wouldn't require the determinant of the Jacobian matrix to be tractable. Of course, the estimation of the desity in data space is not easy in this case. But we have a generation model.

Can someone explain why the generation side is shall not be ignored?